# Using ng-options with 2 data models

Tags: angularjs

I've got this select populating the options using ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="selectedState" name="state_select" id="state_select" 
        style="float:left;" ng-options="item.State for item in Info | orderBy: 'State'"
        ng-change="stateSelected(this)">
    <option value="">Please select a State</option>
</select>
```

Currently it populates with the state abbreviations in both the value and the text of the options. I need to put the state NAMES in the text vs. the state Abbreviations.
The state abbreviations come over in the Info.State values and I have an array of state names:

```
$scope.StatesArray = {"AL": "Alabama","AK": "Alaska","AZ": "Arizona","AR": "Arkansas","CA": "California","CO": "Colorado","CT": "Connecticut",
                      "DE": "Delaware","DC": "District of Columbia","FL": "Florida","GA": "Georgia","HI": "Hawaii","ID": "Idaho","IL": "Illinois",
                      "IN": "Indiana","IA": "Iowa","KS": "Kansas","KY": "Kentucky","LA": "Louisiana","ME": "Maine","MD": "Maryland","MA": "Massachusetts",
                      "MI": "Michigan","MN": "Minnesota","MS": "Mississippi","MO": "Missouri","MT": "Montana","NE": "Nebraska","NV": "Nevada",
                      "NH": "New Hampshire","NJ": "New Jersey","NM": "New Mexico","NY": "New York","NC": "North Carolina","ND": "North Dakota",
                      "OH": "Ohio","OK": "Oklahoma","OR": "Oregon","PA": "Pennsylvania","PR": "Puerto Rico","RI": "Rhode Island","SC": "South Carolina",
                      "SD": "South Dakota","TN": "Tennessee","TX": "Texas","UT": "Utah","VT": "Vermont","VA": "Virginia","WA": "Washington",
                      "WV": "West Virginia","WI": "Wisconsin","WY": "Wyoming"};
```

How would I make the VALUE of the `<option>` be the state abbrev and the TEXT be the State name like this:?

```
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MIGHT be able to do this (untested)

```
ng-options="item.State as StatesArray[item.State] for item in Info
```

Or since you have an object with both appreviation and full name:

```
ng-options="key as state for (key, state) in StateArray"
```

Comment: Produces this: `<option value="0">Alaska</option>` vs. `<option value="AK">Alaska</option>`

Comment: @MB34 -- Updated the answer, give that a whirl

Comment: The only problem is that since I'm using the item in the selector, it actually returns the full item when it is selected. If I use the last solution, it only returns the state abbrev. I'll work on it some more.

Comment: Depending on what info you, set a `ng-change` attribute that takes in the info you need.

Comment: It is actually working now that I changed the code in your first solution to `item` vs. `item.State`